# Weird word order in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

> Zum allerersten Mal hörte einen der neue Partner Dialekt sprechen.

I'm quite confused by this sentence. I would try to reform it like this:

> Der neue Partner hörte zum allerersten **einen** Dialekt sprechen.

But I think **einen** here refers to the Akkusativ of "man". Thus I would translate it to this:

> The new partner heard for the very first time a person speaking a dialekt.

Is what I wrote correct? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

PS: I have inserted a picture of the text, from which I took this sentence.[image: Here]

Comment: And that's why Germany won't have any dialect speakers left in a couple of generations. As a dialect speaker whose standard German is better than that of most Germans: I think this text is pretty strange. It's grammatically correct, but it's not a well written article. It's clearly visible where they artificially and unnaturally fitted in certain grammatical cases or less common vocabulary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got the grammar almost right, however, there are two different cases of *einen* usage:

> 1. **Die meisten Menschen**, die Dialekt sprechen, haben erlebt: Der neue Partner hörte **einen** zum ersten Mal Dialekt sprechen.
> 2. Der neue Partner hörte zum allerersten Mal einen (~jemanden) Dialekt sprechen.

The meaning of *einen* in (1) is different from (2): instead of meaning *any person*/*any dialect*, it refers to *allermeiste Menschen, die...* from the first sentence and their specific dialect.

So it doesn't mean that the new partner for the first time hears an arbitrary person speaking some dialect (which is virtually impossible living in the D/A/CH area), but that the new partner hears *his/her* partner speaking *his/her* dialect for the first time (with people from his/her childhood). *Einen* can be the accusative of *man*, but in this case a previously specified *man*. So in English it would read:

> Most people who learned a dialect before Standard German may have experienced a situation like this: [...] an old friend called and their partner heard **them** for the very first time speaking in [their] dialect.

---

Your suggestion

> Der neue Partner hörte zum allerersten Mal einen Dialekt sprechen.

is possible and common for case (2) mentioned above, but uncommon in the context of (1) because *einen* is a personal pronoun here. Compare the standard word order of:

> Der neue Partner hörte *ihn* zum allerersten Mal Dialekt sprechen.

The original word order is also less ambiguous: in *hörte einen Dialekt sprechen*, the word *einen* could be the article of *Dialekt*, while in *hörte einen zum allerersten Mal Dialekt sprechen* it is clear that *einen* is the direct object.

(I'm not sure if you were arguing that *hörte zum ersten Mal* makes more sense than *zum ersten Mal Dialekt sprechen*, but in both cases *zum ersten Mal* can refer to *hörte* rather than to *Dialekt sprechen*.)

Maybe the appearence of *einen* apart from a noun is somewhat unusual for DaF speakers, but I can assure you it's perfectly fine because you can think of it as a pronoun like *ihn*, *sie*, *es* etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're quite correct, congratulations on not being fooled by the misleading form! (It should be added that even to a native speaker, the inflected forms of 'man' sound somewhat weird, but they're the only ones we have.)

Comment: It really confused me xD. Thank you.

Comment: Even as a native speaker I read this sentence two times until be sure about the meaning :D

Comment: Genau das geschah mir als auch, sogar nach dem dritten Lesen erschloss sich mir nicht der Sinn des Satzes ...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have explained the meaning of *einen* in the sentence "Und zum allerersten Mal hörte *einen* der neue Partner Dialekt sprechen."

Taking the text as a whole, it seems to me that it is not very good German because the use of *einen* is stylistically inadequate.

- Sentence 1: Die allermeisten Menschen [...] dürften eine solche [... ] Geschichte  erlebt haben :
- Sentence 2: Sie hatten sich verliebt [...]
  I include the two "Oder"-rudiments into sentence 2.
- Sentence 3: Und zum allerersten Mal hörte einen der neue Partner Dialekt sprechen.
- Sentence 4: Die Angerufenen fürchteten [...]

It is not absolutely clear what "Sie" in sentence 1 means: (a) It could be the pronoun "they" (for *die allermeisten Menschen*) or (b) the author could address the reader with the formal "Sie".

In case (a) I would expect *sie* (again for *die allermeisten Menschen* or perhaps for *die Angerufenen* in sentence 4) instead of *einen*. This "sie" would also fit perfectly  to sentence 4.

In case (b) I would expect another *Sie* instead of *einen*.